# Not getting value from function that my teacher gave me to use stored procedure SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

My teacher gave me function in order to use stored procedure:

```
public static int SPExecNonQuery
    (string config,
     string procName,
     params object[] prm)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString =
            System.Configuration.
            ConfigurationManager.
            ConnectionStrings[config].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = procName;
        for (int i = 0; i < prm.Length - 1; i += 2)
        {
            string name = prm[i].ToString();
            object value = prm[i + 1];
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, value);
        }
        SqlParameter prmReturn = new SqlParameter("@RETURN", SqlDbType.Int);
        prmReturn.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(prmReturn);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return (int)prmReturn.Value;
}
```

But I always get the value 0 when I am using it.

This is the stored procedure that I used:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Ilan_InsertZoo
@zooName nvarchar(30),
@zooCountry nvarchar(30),
@zooStreet nvarchar(30),
@zooAdress nvarchar(30),
@numOfAnimals nvarchar(30),
@avgVisitorAMonth int,
@ticketPrice int,
AS
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT INTO Ilan_TblZoos (ZooName, ZooCountry, ZooStreet, ZooAdress, NumOfAnimals, AvgVisitorAMonth, TicketPrice) 
  VALUES (@zooName, @zooCountry, @zooStreet, @zooAdress, @numOfAnimals, @avgVisitorAMonth, @ticketPrice)
```

Can someone tell me why? and what should I do?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your teacher wants to know if the insert was successful or not.  So you need to return a value from your stored procedure.

```
---Put this code at the end of your stored procedure
DECLARE @Return int
SET @Return = @@ROWCOUNT
Return @Return
```

The @@ROWCOUNT will return the number of rows inserted. If the insert is successful, then you should get a 1 returned to you.

You may also want to do some research on handling errors in stored procedures.

Comment: Its didnt work for me
I put that code at the end:
[link](http://prntscr.com/2ln451)

Comment: Did you ALTER the procedure by pressing F5 or the Execute button?  Also, remove the "Select" before @@ROWCOUNT

Comment: I ALTER the procedure by pressing Ctrl + F5

Comment: See my comment above.  Remove the word "Select" before @@RowCount

Comment: Not Ctrl + F5, just F5